# NetBeans's include path doesn't work

Tags: php, zend-framework, netbeans

I have a NetBeansProject that works on ZendFramework (the library) and uses PHPUnit to do the tests but each time some function of the Zend Framework is called (the bootstrap file calls them for example) it gives a fatal error because it can't find those files:
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\htdocs\pear;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in....

My bootstrap file looks like this:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 2);

defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
|| define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'testing'));

defined('LIBRARY_PATH')
    || define('LIBRARY_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../library'));

defined('TESTS_PATH')
    || define('TESTS_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));


//Define constant global variable
defined('_FOO_ROOT_DIR_') || define('_FOO_ROOT_DIR_', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
defined('_FOO_APP_DIR_') || define('_FOO_APP_DIR_', _FOO_ROOT_DIR_ . '/application');
defined('_FOO_LIB_DIR_') || define('_FOO_LIB_DIR_', _FOO_ROOT_DIR_ . '/library');
defined('_FOO_PUBLIC_DIR_') || define('_FOO_PUBLIC_DIR_', _FOO_ROOT_DIR_ . '/public');
defined('_FOO_TEST_DIR_') || define('_FOO_TEST_DIR_', _FOO_ROOT_DIR_ . '/tests');
defined('_FOO_ZF_DIR_') || define('_FOO_ZF_DIR_', 'C:\zend\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library');

require_once 'Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php';
.
.
.
.
#End of bootstrap.php
```

and that require_once is what triggers the error. If for example I modify the bootstrap file and instead of doing the require from 'Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php' I do it from _FOO_ZF_DIR_.'/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php' then the problem gets solved, but I have to rewrite every single include from every single file of the Zend library.

The path to the framework on the include is correct, and I have configured my PHPUnit with the bootstrap file I partially copied above and that phpunit.xml that was already given to me by my partner who has the project set and running.

The phpunit.xml looks like this (I don't know if it's relevant to the topic):

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./bootstrap.php" colors="true">
    <testsuite name="ApplicationTestSuite">
        <directory>./application/</directory>
        <directory>./library/</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">../application</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory suffix=".php">../application/modules/pal</directory>
                <directory suffix=".phtml">../application/views</directory>
                <file>../application/Bootstrap.php</file>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="./log/coveragereport" charset="UTF-8"
             yui="true" highlight="false" lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70"/>
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

I have also configured the Zend tab on the options tools, registering the provider and such.
So how could I fix this so that the NetBeans can detect that the includes have to be found not only in relation to the project folder but also in relation to the included library path?

I've also tried to include the library through the global php includes and the project specific ones (through project properties) and neither of them works...

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
I forgot to include the path to the ZendFramework library on the php.ini file.

This is what I had:
    include_path=".;C:\xampp\htdocs\pear;C:\xampp\php\PEAR"

And this is what is required for it to work:
    include_path=".;C:\xampp\htdocs\pear;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\zend\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library"

Regards!